# TCP - Recv-Q not receiving bytes properly

Tags: tcp

Tcp, recv-Q is non-zero value - those connections are in CLOSE_WAIT state

In my application lot of connections are in CLOSE_WAIT state, but i dont know what is the reason for that, but the same program is working properly different machine.

In this case when i execute the netstat command lots of connections are in CLOSE_WAIT state, and recv Q buffer is 1, i don't know what is the reason for this issue

Someone please help me to resolve this.

OS (issue occurs in)
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)[image]